# Any way to Press F5 and insantly run Python3 in External Mac Terminal with VS Code with Window ON TOP?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, runtime

Is there a way to run Python3 code in the Mac External Terminal (Terminal.app) by pressing F5 in Visual Studio Code?

At the moment, I press CMD+SHIFT+A to open the Terminal, then press a Macro on my mouse to type out "python3 " then I type in the program name and hit enter.

Doing it this way is annoying and the in-built internal terminal is not for me.

Another issue for me is, with other IDEs, when ran, the Terminal Window appears BEHIND all other windows when F5 or Run button is pressed.

Any way to open externally and with window on top?

EDIT:

This is my `launch.json` file:

````
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (External Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]```
````

Comment: Did you try to create a launch config? Try to create one [reading this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) and update your post with the `launch.json`

Comment: Using this I have successfully managed to open in External Terminal, however, the second part of my question is unanswered unfortunately. The Terminal Window does not Open, when Launched via F5, In Front of all other windows including my VS Code Window, meaning I have to press F5, then click my Terminal App Window on my Dock. Any way to modify VS Code or Mac OS in a way to make sure Terminal ALWAYS Opens on Top when ran?

Comment: can you add your `launch.json` to your question?

Comment: I have added the launch.json file.

Comment: can you add this to your settings.json and try? `"terminal.external.osxExec": "Terminal.app"` it looks like its a macOS thing because the terminal opens on top on windows.

Comment: This is already there in the settings.json file. F5 runs fine, just opens behind windows and it's really annoying.